# need to display main headers and sub headers in table view dynamically ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to display tableview with two headers.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

need to load those data dynamically, with two headers.

Comment: How do you want to load your data dynamically, using a JSON source? Your process could be use an array of data objects to populate your tableview, update your data objects and then reload your tableview.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return "Bat-and-ball"
        case 1:
            return "Hockey"
        default:
            return "other header"
        }
    }
```

Comment: changing the title won't be enough.

Comment: Sports is main header and need to display the sub-header like "Bat and ball", "Hockey", etc. After that need to display rows.